# Cannot print with Canon IP1200 printer

Tags: 11.10, drivers, printing, canon

I was happy to find that finally there's a driver for my Canon ip1200 printer which as of 11.04 was not available.

Plugged my USB cable and printer is recognized properly. Right click on the printer then  to Properties -> Settings. Then I click on the "Print Test Page" Button. Page rendering progress is shown, printer's light starts blinking. But nothing comes out! Printer works fine from windows. Any ideas? Please help, this is what's been keeping me from fully moving to Linux!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem as described by you!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head - if the printer light is blinking it could be something simple in the settings like the wrong paper size or paper tray option.

When I had an issue installing my ip5200 I did read a [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11120712&postcount=2) about other Canon drivers but then my printer started working so I didn't need them.